# Getting approval from Admin first before posting a blog in Django

Tags: python, django

I have made a blog as a project and I have set users to submit posts for the blog directly but i want to direct this post to the admin first for approval before showing on the website. here is the Post Create View Class.

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
model = Post
fields = ['title', 'content']
template_name = "post_form.html"

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

If there are any tutorials or even guidelines to follow 
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you will want to add a field to your Post model, something like `admin_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)`. When creating your view used to fetch the list of articles for display to the public, make sure to filter by `Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)`. Finally, set up a django_admin for Posts, and allow filtering/sorting by `admin_approved`. Then all you have to do is create an admin action that flips that field to True.

Comment: I've done as instructions and I got a button in the admin to approve the post but new posts are published still